# Login screen never appears

Tags: boot

I am not able to log in to Ubuntu. When I start my laptop and select Ubuntu, the screen with the Ubuntu logo and progress bar dots is shown. I wait for some time but it doesn't show me the login screen. I have tried to restart it but the same problem occurs.
I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Please do the following so you can show us more info about what is not working. When the ubuntu option appears in the menu press E for Edit. Go to the line that starts with LINUX and press E again. Go to the end of the line which should say QUIET SPLASH. Remove the words QUIET SPLASH and press enter. Then press B for Boot. What you did back there was remove the splash logo and tell linux to show you what linux is doing while it boots. It will tell you everything but if it is getting stuck somewhere it will say it normally in the last line. Show us what is the last line or where it gets stuck.

Comment: when i does the step mentioned above.After press B b is typed as char it does not boot system but when i press ctrl+x then it boot system shows me the terminal

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Find the line: `LINUX_CMDLINE_DEFAULT` and add this between the "": `quiet nosplash nohz=off`

Then:

`sudo update-grub`

Do all this in a terminal window, of course, and then reboot.

Comment: he can't login.  He cannot run anything if he can't login or boot.

Comment: I don't think a vote down is deserved...he can edit GRUB at boot time by pressing "A" before the boot screen and then selecting the current kernel and pressing "E" and finally "F10". I've done it both ways (GUI and boot).